# ng-select don't set value on reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngselect

I have a ng-select and angular reactive forms. I configured it:

```
this.form1 = this.fb.group({
  test: [null, null]
});


this.items = [
    {
     code: 'A',
     description: 'TEST A'
    },
    {
     code: 'B',
     description: 'TEST B'
    }

 ]

   <ng-select [items]="items" 
       (change)="onSelected($event)"
       bindLabel="description"
       class="selectbox"> 
    </ng-select>  


onSelected(event){
   this.form1.controls['test'].setValue(event);

   // this.form1.controls['test'].value =  {code: 'A',description: 'TEST A'}
}
```

Now the ng-select works. But if I set value on init i try to make

```
  this.form1.patchValue({
     test: {code: A}
  })
```

but don't worlks. I would like to set ui-select on init with this.form1.patchValue({
         test: {code: A}
      })

any ideas? Thank's
Marco

Answer (score 4):

bind formControlname to ng-select, and then on init set

`this.form1.patchValue({
     test: {code: A}
  })` or if your ng-select is set to [multiple]="true" then

`this.form1.patchValue({
     test: [{code: A}]
  })`